# Condition for 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to create a condition, if the user selects Radio button A, the button will be this one.

```
<input type="button" disabled="disabled" name="next" value="Proceed to Payment" onclick="window.location='shipping.php#openModal'"/>
```

but when user selects Radio button B, the button will automattically be.

```
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" name="order" value="Proceed to Checkout"/>
```

how do i do that? thank you

Comment: I have no idea how to use javascript, i am just a newbie. @Ohgodwhy

Comment: Make some attempts, let us know when you have trouble with your code.

Comment: Are you asking to achieve this , using one button only?

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

Assign an `id` to each of your buttons (that will allow you later to select them like $('#id') ) and set them a style rule, `display: none`. Due to this rule both of them will not be visible, when you page will be loaded.

```
<input id="buttonA" style="display: none" type="button" disabled="disabled" 
       name="next" value="Proceed to Payment" 
       onclick="window.location='shipping.php#openModal'"/>
```

and

```
<input id="buttonB" style="display: none" type="submit" disabled="disabled" 
       name="order" value="Proceed to Checkout"/>
```

Then you could write a jquery handler for the effect of click on radio in the body of whom you could do this:

```
function()
{
    if($('#radioButtonAId').checked())
    {
        $('#buttonA').show();
    }

    if($('#radioButtonBId').checked())
    {
        if($('#buttonB').show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. place both buttons in 1 div with an id
2. define CSS class: .invisible{display:none}
3. add the "invisible" class to the button, that is invisible on start
4. create event handler for the change event of radiobutton
5. in the event handler toggle the "invisible" class by all button children of the div from step 1 (find it using its id)

Answer (score 0):

```
var R1 = document.getElementById('rb1');
var R2 = document.getElementById('rb2');

R1.onchange = function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById('buttonA').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('buttonB').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('buttonA').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('buttonB').style.display = 'block';
    }
}


R2.onchange = function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById('buttonA').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('buttonB').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('buttonA').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('buttonB').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```